# Handwriting features just like fiinote handwriting

Tags: inkcanvas

I m trying to develop windows application in which user will write something on canvas and whatever user write it will show in notepad in same writing style just font size will be different and it will past ok notepad. Just like Fiinote android application handwriting one.

Please help me what I need for that.PLease suggest.

I m new in development so don't have much experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Think of Canvas as a paper. When you draw something on a paper you are drawing a path of the character. Similarly on canvas there is a path. You can let user draw their stuff and record their path.
On paper you use different colored pen to draw, in canvas that functionality is provided by Paint object.

So you need to learn following 
Custom View : How to create your view in which user will draw their stuff.

TouchHandling : You can set your view to receive touch events. Think of device screen as 2D graph. Whenever user moves their finger on screen your view will get touch event with x,y co-ordinates of current point. You can use Path to join together points to display user’s drawing on your canvas.
Paint : provides styling for drawn stuff.

Finally to save notes generated by user, you need to save your path and associated styling info in DB. For this, preferred approach would be to save(draw) user stuff onto a bitmap and save that bitmap in DB.